# Show that $\frac{S_n - \mathbb{E}S_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\left(X_{n}\right)$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = \sigma^2$ for every $n$. Assume that $1 \leq k \leq n,$ there exists $c>0$ such that $X_{k}-\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k}\right] \leq c$ almost surely

$$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k} \quad \text { et } \quad v_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \operatorname{Var}\left(X_{k}\right) = n\sigma^2$$

Show that if $\mathbb{P}\left(S_{n}-\mathbb{E}\left[S_{n}\right] \geq x\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2\left(v_{n}+x c / 3\right)}\right)$ then $\frac{S_n - \mathbb{E}S_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$  converges to a standard normal variable.

assume also that $x = o(n)$.

normally I would just apply the limit central theorem directly but the fact that I wouldn't be using all the assumptions makes me think it can't be done in a straightforward fashion.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AlexR. yes they are, forgot to mention it, fixed.

Comment: This is weird. Just defining $Y_n=X_n-E[X_n]$ gets the result immediately by CLT with only assuming variances are all $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @AlexR. that's exactly what I wanted to use too but teacher insisted on noticing that the right hand side of the inequality is equivalent to $\exp \left(-x^{2} / 2 \sigma^{2} n\right)$ and making use of it.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think I know now why it can't be used directly, we don't have identically distributed random variables, will look into the other versions of CLT, thanks !